# DownloadManager doesn't downlooad right

Tags: java, android

I have Class which download files with `DownloadManager`.

I call this class from `MainActivity` with 1 argument which can be rzeszow,warszawa or krakow.

Problem is that it doesnt download this files right, they should have 18.4kB but they have 17.9kB, if i download file buses_users with this class it downloads right. Here is my class

```
package com.example.buses;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;

class Downloading extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog = null;
    String city;
    String lastUpdateString;

    private final Context context;
    public Downloading(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
    }

    enter code here
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... names) {
        String dest_file_path = "/Android/data/com.example.buses/databases/" + User.getCurrentUser() + '/';
        String dwnload_file_path = "http://emy-projects.pp.ua/buses_users/ + names[0];
        DownloadManager mgr=null;
        long lastDownload;
        city = names[0];

        mgr=(DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(dwnload_file_path);
        DownloadManager.Request req=new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        Uri dst_uri = Uri.parse(dest_file_path);
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(dst_uri.getPath()).mkdirs();
        req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                                       | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
           .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
           .setTitle("Demo")
           .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
           .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(dst_uri.getPath(),
                                              "buses_database");
        lastDownload=mgr.enqueue(req);
        try{
            URL url = new URL(dwnload_file_path);
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            long date = httpCon.getLastModified();
            lastUpdateString = Long.toString(date);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            return null; 
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        MainActivity.pDialog.dismiss();
        MainActivity.dbHelper.insertNewUser(User.getCurrentUser(), city, lastUpdateString);
        MainActivity.currentCity = city;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You invoke DownloadManager in the doInbackgroud from an AsyncTask. That is not ok. You should do that on the main thread. After that you make an `url.openConnection();` to the same url ... well ok. Please do the download not in an asynctask or thread. If you want you can do it in onPreExecute.

Comment: `if i download file buses_users with this class it downloads right. Here is my class` ???? ?????? Then what is the problem? You confuse me as you use DownloadManager here too.

Comment: thx I will try you 1st comment, about 2nd: i download buses_users not here, here i dont have to download this one, just "rzeszow/warszawa/krakow". I wrote about buses_users because its strange that it download some files right and some dont.

Comment: Don't understand what you are talking about `` We only see one url `http://emy-projects.pp.ua/buses_users/buses_users` . Are you telling that this code downloads ok from that url? And that it downloads wrong from other urls? If so then post the other urls.

Comment: oh, deam, that's my fail, i already edited that. Sorry

Comment: My god how do we know what is names? Just post three or four complete urls so we do not have to gues. Tell for each url in bytes (not in KB) what it's length should be.

Comment: I wrote, names can be rzeszow/warszawa/krakow, i get url right and its not problem with this, if i write exactly for examble rzeszow i still have this problem and file still has 17.9 kB

Comment: here are this urls http://emy-projects.pp.ua/buses_users/rzeszow       http://emy-projects.pp.ua/buses_users/warszawa               http://emy-projects.pp.ua/buses_users/krakow

Comment: If i download `http://emy-projects.pp.ua/buses_users` with DownloadManage it's exactly 18.432 bytes. About which file are you talking? You have four url's so four files. Tell for each the file length please.

Comment: ok, in this class i have to download **rzeszow/warszawa/krakow**, every one has 18.432 B, because they are the same, just different name, I had in my code in url **buses_users** just to **try** will it download this file right, it does, but if i download **rzeszow/warszawa/krakow** it doesn't download them right.

Comment: Man where are you talking about? Tell which url you use exactly please. `http://emy-projects.pp.ua/buses_users/krakow` does not exist. And the others give a 404 Not Found too. You can check that with any browser.

Comment: hmm, that's strange, because i can download this files from both of my computers, i wrote this urls few comments before

Comment: Sorry. The urls are ok. I did something wrong. Now tell exactly the number of bytes please. What they have to be and what you get. Exactly!

Comment: i have to get file which has 18432 but i get 18413

Comment: Here for all three Downloadmanager delivers files of 18432 bytes.

Comment: did you make test project for this and it work's well?

Comment: No. Somewhere i had already an app/some code with a downloadmanager. I just put your urls in it. But... `dest_file_path` is the same for all your downloads. You should add names[[] there too.

Comment: i know about **dest_file_path** it has to be the same, and final file which i get is always **buses_database**

Comment: No. During this test you should use different destination files. And did you take it completely out of the asynctask? Don't use the url connection while testing. Concentrate on your download problem only.

Comment: ok, thanx for your time, i'll try to take out from asynctask. And what is strang, i have 1 more class which download **buses_users** (about which i sad before) and this class is exactly the same except onPostExecute (it has URLConnection too). So i tried to download **rzeszow/krakow/warszawa** and it works well.